# Dynamically adding Page URL and Page Title into html Link

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am attempting to create some custom social sharing icons using Font-awesome.

I started out with the following code:

```
    <span>Share this article:</span>
<a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={{url}}&title={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{url}}&title={{title}}&source={{source}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status={{title}}+{{url}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

So what I am trying to do is replace the Current Page url into the {{url}} and the current page title into the {{title}} tags.

Using the following code I can obtain the page url:

```
$uri = JUri::getInstance();
```

But when trying to insert this into just the {{url}} part as below it breaks on the {{title}}.

```
<a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u="<?php echo $uri ?>"title={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Can anyone possibly advise the best way to do this so that it remains dynamic to share the current page?

Comment: Hi Dtorr: Is this a module or plugin, or you write this in the article's body? I also see syntax errors In your code snipped above. You start wrapping the href attribute with the double quotes and you are closing them before you open the <?php tags to echo the $uri ... and so on. So first of all you have to make sure you are using correct syntax. (This type of syntax errors questions are off-topic in JSE). Then I would advise to consult the FB API Docs and the other Social media's API for how you can use their sharer features.

Comment: @Dtorr Please progress this question toward a resolution.  If my answer doesn't solve your issue I am happy to delete it or adjust it.  Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this seems to be a simple typo-type question, but it does present a chance to show the appropriate php function to generate a properly url-encoded querystring.

`http_build_query()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

This allows you to write clean, readable code by declaring an array to be converted to a valid querystring (you have to write the leading `?`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YDDgY))

```
$query_params = [
    'u' => 'thisistheuristring with spaces and an & sign',
    'title' => 'The Title is Awesome! Right?'
];
?>
<a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?<?php echo http_build_query($query_params) ?>" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Output:

```
<a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=thisistheuristring+with+spaces+and+an+%26+sign&title=The+Title+is+Awesome%21+Right%3F" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Pay particular notice that:

- spaces are converted to `+`
- `&` is converted to `%26`
- `!` is converted to `%21`
- `?` is converted to `%3F`
- (effectively, this call does all of the necessary encoding for you)

The only gotcha worth mentioning is: **If you pass a `null` value to the function call, there will be no trace of the key or value in the output**.  In other words if you passed it an array containing `'title' => null`, then you won't see `title=` in the query string ...it will completely ignore the declaration.

---

More specific to your question, you could alternatively code it these ways (because you are only writing one php variable into your query string):

```
$query_params['u'] = 'thisistheuristring with spaces and an & sign';
?>
<a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?<?php echo http_build_query($query_params) ?>&title={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

or

```
$uri = 'thisistheuristring with spaces and an & sign';
?>
<a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($uri) ?>&title={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: agree with @Zollie - this is a good post

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you - the problem I see is that your code requires me to assign a value rather than dynamically obtain the URL/Title from the Joomla core using the correct parameters?

Comment: I don't have a ready-solution for you using pure mustache syntax.  I was under the impression that you where happy to merely fix the php implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You have misplaced quotes around PHP tags and missing the ampersand (`&`) before the title.

```
<a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php echo $uri ?>&title={{title}}" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Also you should run the variables used in URL through `urlencode()`.